# Bin file installation problem: "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: linux, qt, slackware

I downloaded Qt SDK  file (530 MB and file is ok) qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin. 
I typed in the console (slackware), like in the manual for installation at the site:

> chmod u+x
>   qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin

But when I type the second command for installation:

> ./qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin

I get an error message:

> bash:
>   ./qt-sdk-linux-x86_64-opensource-2010.05.1.bin:
>   cannot execute binary file

How to install?

Comment: `file` against it says...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error message, the file is `qt-sdk-linux-x86-opensource-2010.05.1.bin`, yet the error mentions `qt-sdk-linux-x86_64-opensource-2010.05.1.bin` (**x86_64** instead of **x86**). It could be you've got a version for a difference architecture than yours - `uname -a` should give you some pointers as to what architecture you're on.

Comment: Good find! Or maybe the `x86` version tries to invoke the `x86_64` version, and hence that `x86_64` version needs to be executable too? If so, then just run `chmod u+x qt-sdk-linux-x86_64-opensource-2010.05.1.bin`